# Dynamically created element in JQuery keeps on appending to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Here is my problem:

I have this mother of all JQuery code that generate a JQuery UI dialog dynamically and then bind some event and some code on its. Problem is that this dynamic element keep appending to my DOM and brake the execution of javascript.

here is the code:

```
$(
    function()
    {
        $("#rn_INVITE_1").on //This is a button
        (
            "click",
            function()
            {
                $.ajax
                (
                    {
                        url:"prc.php",
                        type:"POST",
                        data:{invite:"someData"},
                        contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
                    }
                ).done
                (
                    function(data)
                    {
                        $(
                            '<div id="rn_INVITER_1" name="rn_INVITE_1" title="Inviter:">'+
                                '<div style="clear:both;"><br></div>'+
                                '<label for="rn_INVITER_TXT_1">Inviter:</label>'+
                                '<input id="rn_INVITER_TXT_1" name="rn_INVITER_TXT_1" type="text" size="50" value="'+data+'"/>'+
                                '<div style="clear:both;"><br></div>'+
                            '</div>'
                        ).dialog
                        (
                            {
                                resizable: false,
                                modal: true,
                                height: 250,
                                width: 900,
                                buttons:
                                {
                                    Close:
                                    function()
                                    {
                                        $.ajax
                                        (
                                            {
                                                url:"prc.php",
                                                type:"POST",
                                                data:
                                                {
                                                    event: "inviter",
                                                    inviter: $("#rn_INVITER_TXT_1").val(),
                                                    sama:"person1",
                                                    dtstart:"2014-08-15 16:14:30"
                                                },
                                                contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
                                            }
                                        ).done
                                        (
                                            function(poiu)
                                            {
                                                console.log(poiu);
                                            }
                                        );

                                        $(this).dialog("close");
                                    }
                                },
                                create:
                                function()
                                {
                                    $("#rn_INVITER_TXT_1").autocomplete
                                    (
                                        {
                                            minlength: 0,
                                            source:
                                            function(request, response)
                                            {
                                                //user is already created elsewhere. 
                                                response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(user, extractLast(request.term)));
                                            },
                                            focus:
                                            function()
                                            {
                                                return false;
                                            },
                                            select:
                                            function(event, ui)
                                            {
                                                //split is define elsewhere
                                                var terms = split(this.value);
                                                terms.pop();
                                                terms.push(ui.item.value);
                                                terms.push("");
                                                this.value = terms.join(", ");
                                                return false;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    );
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
);
```

On the DOM side I start with a simple button :

```
<input id="rn_INVITE_1" name="rn_INVITE_1" class="ui-corner-all ui-state-active" type="button" style="width:200px;float:left;" value="Inviter"/>
```

When I click `rn_INVITE_1` for the first time everything is cool and work just fine. Then the DOM looks like this:

```
<input id="rn_INVITE_1" name="rn_INVITE_1" class="ui-corner-all ui-state-active" type="button" style="width:200px;float:left;" value="Inviter"/>
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="height: auto; width: 900px; top: 204px; left: 505.5px; display: none;" aria-describedby="rn_INVITER_1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5">
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
        <span id="ui-id-5" class="ui-dialog-title">Inviter:</span>
        <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
            <span class="ui-button-text">close</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="rn_INVITER_1" name="rn_INVITE_1" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 97px;">
        <div style="clear:both;"><br></div>
        <label for="rn_INVITER_TXT_1">Inviter:</label>
        <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
        <input id="rn_INVITER_TXT_1" name="rn_INVITER_TXT_1" type="text" size="50" value="some value" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
        <div style="clear:both;"><br></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
        <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
            <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                <span class="ui-button-text">Close</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-6" tabindex="0" style="display: none;">
    </ul>
</div>
```

I guess this code is ok since its the code JQuery generated. But if close the newly generated/opened UI Dialog and reopen it the code is reappend to the DOM then it looks like this:

```
<input id="rn_INVITE_1" name="rn_INVITE_1" class="ui-corner-all ui-state-active" type="button" style="width:200px;float:left;" value="Inviter"/>
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="height: auto; width: 900px; top: 204px; left: 505.5px; display: none;" aria-describedby="rn_INVITER_1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5">
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
        <span id="ui-id-5" class="ui-dialog-title">Inviter:</span>
        <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
            <span class="ui-button-text">close</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="rn_INVITER_1" name="rn_INVITE_1" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 97px;">
        <div style="clear:both;"><br></div>
        <label for="rn_INVITER_TXT_1">Inviter:</label>
        <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
        <input id="rn_INVITER_TXT_1" name="rn_INVITER_TXT_1" type="text" size="50" value="some value" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
        <div style="clear:both;"><br></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
        <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
            <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                <span class="ui-button-text">Close</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-6" tabindex="0" style="display: none;">
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="height: auto; width: 900px; top: 204px; left: 505.5px; display: none;" aria-describedby="rn_INVITER_1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5">
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
        <span id="ui-id-5" class="ui-dialog-title">Inviter:</span>
        <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
            <span class="ui-button-text">close</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="rn_INVITER_1" name="rn_INVITE_1" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 97px;">
        <div style="clear:both;"><br></div>
        <label for="rn_INVITER_TXT_1">Inviter:</label>
        <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
        <input id="rn_INVITER_TXT_1" name="rn_INVITER_TXT_1" type="text" size="50" value="some value" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
        <div style="clear:both;"><br></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
        <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
            <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                <span class="ui-button-text">Close</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-6" tabindex="0" style="display: none;">
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="height: auto; width: 900px; top: 204px; left: 505.5px; display: none;" aria-describedby="rn_INVITER_1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5">
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
        <span id="ui-id-5" class="ui-dialog-title">Inviter:</span>
        <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
            <span class="ui-button-text">close</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="rn_INVITER_1" name="rn_INVITE_1" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 97px;">
        <div style="clear:both;"><br></div>
        <label for="rn_INVITER_TXT_1">Inviter:</label>
        <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
        <input id="rn_INVITER_TXT_1" name="rn_INVITER_TXT_1" type="text" size="50" value="some value" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
        <div style="clear:both;"><br></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
        <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
            <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                <span class="ui-button-text">Close</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-6" tabindex="0" style="display: none;">
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="height: auto; width: 900px; top: 204px; left: 505.5px; display: none;" aria-describedby="rn_INVITER_1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5">
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
        <span id="ui-id-5" class="ui-dialog-title">Inviter:</span>
        <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
            <span class="ui-button-text">close</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="rn_INVITER_1" name="rn_INVITE_1" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 97px;">
        <div style="clear:both;"><br></div>
        <label for="rn_INVITER_TXT_1">Inviter:</label>
        <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
        <input id="rn_INVITER_TXT_1" name="rn_INVITER_TXT_1" type="text" size="50" value="some value" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
        <div style="clear:both;"><br></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
        <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
            <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                <span class="ui-button-text">Close</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-6" tabindex="0" style="display: none;">
    </ul>
</div>
```

It repeats its self in the DOM for how many time its open.

Problem is not so much that it repeat itself. its that I now have multiple element with the same ID and that screw up my code real bad.

So I was hoping someone could tell me why its appending the code to the DOM every time the dialog is open.

I am open on trying any solution you guys have to stop the 'appending' from happening.

But I am really just asking what cause this so I can try something myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you create a test case in JSfiddle??

Comment: Sure... I have never use jsfiddle but give me a couples of minutes I'll post back

Comment: here is the jsfiddle but I can't get the JQuery UI Dialog to show... http://jsfiddle.net/vrzjj1xf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to happen because closing the dialog does not mean it is going to destroy the content it added to the DOM , you should destroy the dialog on closing function

```
                   $(this).dialog('destroy').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another options is to remove and existing elements when creating the new

```
 function(data)
                    {
                      **$("#rn_INVITER_1").remove();**
                        $(
                            '<div id="rn_INVITER_1" name="rn_INVITE_1" title="Inviter:">'+
                                '<div style="clear:both;"><br></div>'+
                                '<label for="rn_INVITER_TXT_1">Inviter:</label>'+
                                '<input id="rn_INVITER_TXT_1" name="rn_INVITER_TXT_1" type="text" size="50" value="'+data+'"/>'+
                                '<div style="clear:both;"><br></div>'+
                            '</div>'
                        ).dialog
                        ( .....................
```